# Make center div same size as side div only if center div is smaller

Tags: javascript, css, height

How can I make my center div the same height as the Left SideBar2 if and only if the center div is smaller than the Left SideBar2?
I'm not sure if this can be done with pure CSS or if I should be using JS for this and how?

[My page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqfnz.png)

Comment: You could use media queries

Comment: Check out [this great post](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) on the subject. Let me know if that helps you!

Comment: Do you mean if the center div is smaller than the height of ONLY Left SideBar2 or if there's not enough content in the center div to reach Left SideBar 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be done with javascript... here i'll use jquery.
Put this in your  tags and make appropriate changes.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        function changeHeight() {
            $centerDiv = $('#centerDivId');
            $leftBar = $('#leftBarId');
            if ($centerDiv.height() < $leftBar.height()) {
                $centerDiv.css('height', $leftBar.height())
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this code is not working for me :( it doesn't do anything
notice there is a typo in the $leftbar references it should be $leftBar

Comment: Awesome I glad it helped you out!

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var $center = jQuery('.center-selector');
    $center.height(getCenterHeight());
});

var getCenterHeight = function() {
    var $left = jQuery('.left-sidebar-container-selector');
    var $right = jQuery('.right-sidebar-container-selector');

    var leftHeight = parseInt($left.height(), 10);
    var rightHeight = parseInt($right.height(), 10);

    return Math.max(leftHeight, rightHeight);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use CSS3 `min-height` property to set the [minimum height](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/min-height) of the centered div.